# Class Not Found exception when including a GWT module project as a 'required project'

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jetty

I'm trying to incorporate a GWT Module (A small MVP framework I'm working on) into a GWT project in development mode on the GWT development jetty server. I can do so if I copy the module's source directly into the project. I'm likewise successful if I include a jar containing the module in the project.

My preference, however, is to include the module as a 'required project' for the main project in eclipse, as both the module and the project are under active development. Unfortunately, when I do so the following error is printed to the console when I try to start up the main project in development mode:

```
WARNING: failed greetServlet: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gmles/framework/client/AuthService
Aug 19, 2011 7:33:22 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@7ac412dd{/,/Users/logan/Documents/workspace/HCASchedule/war}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gmles/framework/client/AuthService
Aug 19, 2011 7:33:22 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@4c7335b1: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gmles/framework/client/AuthService
Aug 19, 2011 7:33:22 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gmles/framework/client/AuthService
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:151)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:151)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:185)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:147)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:86)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:500)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1055)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:804)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:309)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gmles.framework.client.AuthService
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:151)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 48 more
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Note that `ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundError` are different.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Changing the output directory of the module project to its own WEB-INF directory doesn't work; same error. I don't want to configure it to output directly to the other project's directory - I might as well just drop the module source into the main project and develop from there if I'm going to do that. The main project is already configured to output to the 'classes' folder within WEB-INF. I've already tried dropping the jar in - it works. I'd really like to be able to just include the module's project so that I can use it in more than one project simultaneously.

Comment: I updated my answer and pulled out what you said didn't work.  I would like what you're talking about too; but I haven't found a way yet.  I think maven might do what you're talking about; and you might be able to write an ANT task which runs when you do a build to make sure the lib folder there is up to date.  Also, if you're on linux, you might be able to make a symbolic link back to your build/lib folder; but so far I haven't seen a cleaner way aside from just dropping the jars in the WEB-INF/lib :/

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try playing around with Maven a little. I have a feeling that the GWT plugin probably just messes with classpath in such a way to cripple eclipses 'required project' mechanism.